# Register child component dynamically in Vuejs

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have a component, let's call it `Parent.vue`(code shown below). It uses the `<component>` tag provided by Vuejs to dynamically render a component.

It takes a prop named `child` which describes the type of the child component and the props it will take.

Now, the problem is that even if my `Parent.vue` renders only 1 child component at a time, it has to register all the 3 components, using the `components` object.

So, my question is: Is there a way to dynamically import and register these child components based on the type of the child? Something like a function that checks the `child.type` field and creates the `components` object with just the child that is required.

Any help would be appreciated

```
<template>
  <div>
    <component 
      :is="getComponentName(child.type)" 
      v-bind="child.props"
    >
    </component>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import Button from './Button.vue'
  import InputText from './InputText.vue'
  import DataTable from './DataTable.vue'

  export default{
    props:{
      child: Object
    },
    components:{
      Button,
      InputText,
      DataTable
    },
    methods:{
      getComponentName(type){
        switch(type){
          case 'button': return 'Button'
          case 'input-text': return 'InputText'
          case 'table': return DataTable
        }
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Hi, would this example https://jsfiddle.net/chrisvfritz/o3nycadu/ help you doing what you want ? It shows how to dynamically switch between components.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used a method along these lines and it works.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <component 
      :is="getComponentName(child.type)" 
      v-bind="child.props"
    >
    </component>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default{
    props:{
      child: Object
    },
    methods:{
      getComponentName(type){
        switch(type){
          case 'button': return require('./components/Button.vue')
          case 'input-text': return require('./components/InputText.vue')
          case 'table': return require('./components/Table.vue')
        }
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks @Andrew1325. Can you tell me why this does not work:
`case 'button': return () => import('./my-async-component./components/Button.vue')` Why do I have to use only `require`

Comment: Yeah, I'm not exactly sure why. Doing it that way is a dynamic import which I think requires a babel plugin to transpile properly.

Answer (score 3):

Since the `is` property of `component` component can accept `ComponentDefinition` (See more about information [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#component)). So you can set it to the factory function which return dynamic import function.

```js
    <template>
      <div>
        <button @click='name = "Apple"'>Apple</button>
        <button @click='name = "Banana"'>Banana</button>
        <component :is='component'/>
      </div>
    </template>
    
    <script>
      export default {
        data: () => ({
          name: 'Apple'
        }),
    
        computed: {
          component () {
            let name = this.name
            return () => import(`@/components/${name}`)
          }
        }
      }
    </script>
```

With this way your component will be load and execute when you use it without explicit register.

Comment: I tried your solution here: https://codesandbox.io/s/r0m5ko9qpq
It gives me an error.

Comment: Please try on your machine. I'm still not sure why.

Comment: I can accept only 1 answer, but, this method is documented in the official Vuejs doc, so this too is correct answer

Comment: Actually there is a big difference between using `require(...)` and `import(...)`. Webpack will not split your chunk if you using `require(...)`, means you will load all components with or without used. If you want to use `require` anyway, you can use special syntax of `require` to tell Webpack to split this file by `() => new Promise(resolve => { require(['./components/Hello.vue'], resolve) })`. Please see https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-dynamic-async.html#Async-Components.

Comment: For future reference: `let name = this.name` **is important** or the computed property will lose its reactivity.